# js Return multi methods for Plugin .apply()

Tags: javascript, plugins, methods, return, return-value

I am trying to return multi method for a plugin.

The structure is like below. If I apply more than one method like:

```
return ob[a].apply(), ob[b].apply();
```

will return error. Please advice!! Thank you very much!!

```
ob = {
 a: function(){ return{ A: function(){   } }},
 b: function(){ return{ B: function(){   } }},

}

$.fn.plugin = function(){
  return ob[a].apply();
}

$(el).plugin().A()
```

I want, return 2 method a and b then I can use plugin like

```
  $(el).plugin().A()
  $(el).plugin().B()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: the convention is that jquery plugins should return the object they were run on, so that you can chain them. also, what is your goal? your apply syntax is wrong. are you trying to get A and B that are bound to the plugins' `this` ?

Comment: no, I want to a way that can apply either A or B like the jQuery || $(el).css().append()     or    $(el).append().css()

Comment: if i a the way return b inside of a, this will work like  $(el).plugin().A().B() , but will can not change to  $(el).plugin().B().A()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript you can only return one object from a function.
So, `return ob[a].apply(), ob[b].apply();` will not work.

You can return an object containing these values. You may be interested in [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically).

An alternate to combining objects dynamically would be to tweak how your code works slightly:

```
ob = {
    a: function(){ return function(){ return 'a';  } },
    b: function(){ return function(){ return 'b';  } },
}     
 function myPlugin() {
     var rv = new Object();
     rv['a'] = ob['a'].apply();
     rv['b'] = ob['b'].apply();
     return rv;
 }
var o = myPlugin();
alert(o.a());
alert(o.b());
```

Comment: i read the giving link, and I tried the way you posted. Now is no error but either $(el).plugin().B() or .A() will not work.

Comment: seem like rv['a'] = ob['a'].apply(); will only give the function from ob['a'] to rv['a'] but will not apply to the way writing plugin. Maybe return cannot be a objective but a function. Please help to give a way return multi functions.